# Does the nth-child(1) of a class has the same result with the class itself if there is only one in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose we have two elements that have the same className for example `."test".`
To get each of them and manipulate them as i wish i can use something like

`$(".test:nth-child(1)")` for the first one and
`$(".test:nth-child(2)")` for the second one

if i replace the first child element with a different element with different class name using `replaceWith` then logically there will be only one child of the `.test` class

then if i use the `$(".test:nth-child(1)")` i should get the second  as the previous first has been changed. right?

But i dont..

now that i have only one element with this class name the

```
$(".test")
```

isnt the same with `$(".test:nth-child(1)")`??

in my code i must use nth-child cause a lot of child elements are added dymanically..

Comment: Quote: "then if i use the $(".test:nth-child(1)") i should get the second as the previous first has been changed. right?". Your assumption here is wrong. `nth-child` and `.class` selector work sepparately, they are not a chained filter.

Comment: In your case, use `:eq(0)` instead of `:nth-child(1)`

Answer (score 3):

No. [`:nth-child`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) doesn't mean "the nth that matches the rest of this selector," it literally means "the nth child of its parent."  jQuery has an [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) extension which means "the nth match for the rest of this selector," but that's an entirely different thing specific to jQuery, not a CSS thing.

Re `:nth-child`: Here's an example where `.foo` and `.foo:nth-child(1)` will not find the same thing:

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="foo">abc</div>
</div>
```

There, `.foo` matches an element, but `.foo:nth-child(1)` does not. The only `.foo` is not also the first child in its parent. Remember that when you combine parts of a selector, you're saying "AND" between them. Just like `img.foo` means "an element with tag `img` AND with class `foo`," `.foo:nth-child(1)` means "an element with class `foo` AND that is the first child in its parent."

Live example:

```css
.foo {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.foo:nth-child(1) {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="foo">abc</div>
</div>
<p>Notice that  <code>.foo</code> finds an element (the text has been transformed to upper case), but <code>.foo:nth-child(1)</code> does not (there's no border around it). The <code>.foo</code> is not also the first child in its parent.</p>
```

There is no "nth of class" in CSS. (There is [`:nth-of-type`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo), which relates to the tag type, not the class.) And, again, the jQuery-only `:eq`.

Answer (score -1):

Using `nth-child` will absolutely suck in the long run, you mentioned

> in my code i must use nth-child cause a lot of child elements are added dymanically..

Well, brilliant, use that and generate an ID unique to each child. Keeping track of nth-* is hard and not easy to understand.